# Questions about "enabling content approval for submitted items", inside my wiki library

Tags: wiki, library, approval-process, content-approval

I have added an enterprise wiki site collection , and I have enabled approving any wiki pages . by doing to “Library setting -- > Versioning Setting -- > Require content approval for submitted items?” Set to Yes. After that whenever I edit or add a new wiki library page, it will require approval to be published.

But I have the following questions about this approval process:-

- Is there a way to list all the wiki pages that require approval ?.  so that any user who need to approve these wikis, can go to this page and view all the wikis, that is waiting his approval ?
- For “Draft Item Security” I set it to “Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)”. But which user permission allow users to be able to approve or reject wikis ?
- Finally, if a user reject a wiki, then the page will stay being displayed with the latest modification, but I was expecting that when rejecting a wiki, to remove any modification made to it. and the author should have the ability to know the status and that his page was rejected ?

So can anyone advice on these questions please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable the content approval you also need to enable major and minor versions in order to work.

Doing so will create a new view on the Pages Library that is called "Approve / Reject" where all the wiki pages are listed that have pending approvals or have been rejected.
[image: Approve and reject view]

**For the permission level:**
There is one permission level that is called approve. This has extended contribution writes and can be assigned to a group or individual users. I recommend to use a group for that.
Contributor rights are not enough. You will find more on permission levels on [http://office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx).

To your third question the approval status is a change on the wiki page therefor it creates a new version and the modified and modified by information will be updated.

Comment: thanks for your helpful reply. but i need to know how i can add a link to the "Approve / Reject" view so that users can easily access it . second question can you explain what do u mean exactly by "To your third question the approval status is a change on the wiki page therefor it creates a new version and the modified and modified by information will be updated.". third question is there a way to configure my wiki library to send emails to all the approval users , when a wiki is waiting their approval ?

Comment: You can link the "Approve / Reject" View on the Quicklaunch to your right. Yes it is possible to send email to all the approver via email but the I suggest you to use a workflow. Whenever a user request an approval the approver will get an email. You will find more on that http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/understand-approval-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010-HA101857172.aspx